# Can only start few applications with Ubuntu 18.04.1 on Lenovo ThinkPad 460s

Tags: 18.04, firefox, performance, thunderbird, thinkpad

I'm currently running 18.04.1 on a T460s. Everything runs smooth except one issue occuring once in a while:

Seems like I'm sometimes not able to start more than one application, e.g. Firefox 64.0 (happened with earlier versions, too) is running and I'm not able to start Thunderbird, or VLC or KeePass or a terminal (to check processes and logfiles or start application from here to get helpful output). Happened with Thunderbird or Gimp running, too. Usually it works again 10min later or I just close this one application running in foreground and afterwards I'm able to start MANY applications in parallel again.
If this happens while Firefox is running, I'm still able to open many, many tabs.

Any suggestions?

**Update #1**
I was able to find this output while starting applications from terminal:

Maximum number of clients reached
(gedit:19473): dbind-WARNING **: 23:49:31.792: Could not open X display

Maximum number of clients reachedUnable to init server

see:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1518411